# Running tests with multiple servers in gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

to run my tests in my local machine in one terminal I run one python server and in another terminal, I run my second server then in the third terminal I run my tests.

What would be the best way to run tests in a similar way in Gitlab CI

Answer (score 0):

Build your servers into docker images and run them using the service keyword in the job. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#services